# New to Java: SuperClass and SubClass

Tags: java, inheritance

I am fairly new to Java and I am learning about Inheritance. I am trying to create a subclass called BetterRectangle under the superclass Rec1.

Rec 1 gets the x and y coordinates (location) and also gets the width and height (size) of the rectangle. BetterRectangle calculates the perimeter and area of the rectangle.

I get errors in the main method. It cannot find any of the symbols (i.e. cannot find rec1.getHeight(20) symbol).

```
public class Rec1 {
    private double x;
    private double y;
    private double width;
    private double height;

    public void setLocation(double xCord, double yCord) {
        x = xCord;
        y = yCord;
    }

    public void setSize(double h, double w) {
        height = h;
        width = w;
    }

    public double getHeight(double h) {
        return height;
    }

    public double getWidth(double w) {
        return width;
    }
}

public class BetterRectangle extends Rectangle {
    public BetterRectangle(int x, int y, int width, int height) {

        super(x, y, width, height);
        super.setLocation(x, y);
        super.setSize(width, height);
    }

    public double calcPerimeter() {
        return super.getHeight() * 2 + super.getWidth() * 2;
    }

    public double calcArea() {
        return super.getHeight() * super.getWidth();
    }
}
```

Comment: You're using class names as variable names. `Rectangle BetterRectangle = new Rectangle();` and `Rectangle Rec1 = new Rectangle();` should both be given different values in the second position.

Comment: To add on to that, `BetterRectangle` should extend `Rec1`.

Comment: Variables should start with lower-case letters - it's not a requirement, just generally considered good style. This will avoid confusion here, where you run the risk of mixing up the class `BetterRectangle` and the variable `BetterRectangle` (which isn't even a `BetterRectangle`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look closely:

```
Rectangle Rec1 = new Rectangle(); 

Rec1.getHeight(20);
```

The type of `Rec1` is `Rectangle`. But the `Rectangle` class doesn't have a `getHeight` method. Maybe you wanted this:

```
Rec1 rec1 = new Rectangle(); 

rec1.getHeight(20);
```

Notice that I renamed the variable to `rec1`, and changed its type.

Answer (score 0):

class BetterRectangle is extending Rectangle in your sample code. So here BetterRectangle would be child and Rectangle would be parent. Now BetterRectangle uses super keyword to access getHeight,getWidth etc...functions. since these functions are not present in Rectangle class it is giving compilation Error.

Instead of extending Rectangle class extend Rec1 class in BetterRectangle and then run the main Class Rectangle. This should work.

Answer (score 0):

Look carefully here

```
   Rectangle BetterRectangle = new Rectangle();
   Rectangle Rec1 = new Rectangle();
```

You are declaring variables of type Rectangle instead of your own classes.  I can't see your import statements but you are likely creating types of java.awt.rectangle.  You're mixing up variable types and variable names.  When creating instances of your own classes it should look like this:

```
Rec1 mySimpleRec = new Rec1();
BetterRectangle myBetterRec = new BetterRectangle()
```

When declaring things put them in this order "Type variableName = new Type()" or "Class variableName = new Class()".